get List of Token created by wallet user on solana
I am currently trying to fetch the tokens which are created by user on solana. so i came to helius,
i am using Helius to fetch all assets
i need only token which are created by user not the NFTs, so i am fetching all then filtering FungibleToken only,
const fetchAssets = async (creatorAddress) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=43fc-98b3-e8e33881664d`,
        {
          jsonrpc: "2.0",
          id: "helius-test",
          method: "searchAssets",
          params: {
            ownerAddress: creatorAddress,
            tokenType: "all",
          },
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );

      const items = response.data?.result?.items || []; // Ensure items array exists
      // Filter for only FungibleToken interface
      const fungibleTokens = items.filter(
        (item) => item.interface === "FungibleToken"
      );
      console.log(items)

      const getAllMetadataSymbols = () => {
        return fungibleTokens
          .map((token) => token.content?.metadata?.symbol) // Extract metadata.symbol
          .filter((symbol) => symbol) // Remove undefined or null values
          .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)); // Sort alphabetically
      };
      console.log(fungibleTokens)
      console.log(getAllMetadataSymbols())
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error); // Handle error
    }
  };

but there are 20 tokens showing created by user on pumpfun
And the array which i am getting is showing 71 tokens
And from those 71, many of pump fun tokens not showing
you can check the token here
https://pump.fun/profile/6i2aHtxfqkC2biTo98FSkP59FVHPKFRLZWDbdghN6WKK 
how can i get the tokens which are created by user?
if any other procedure to fetch token created by user other than helius.
please tell.
any other procedure or solution to this.
